# How i can send commands by ssh of the nativescript application and typescript?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

I need to make a connection to the **nativescript** application with a **linux server** over **SSH**. How can I do this?

If there is any different way to this I would like to know ...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any existing plugin to support that. You might want to write one, there are native libraries like [NMSSH](https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH) for iOS and [jsch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for Android.